# Missing required parameter in yii2 Search

Tags: yii2

i want to search the stock till a particular date. User will fill this date form. The first page where user go to input the date field is _formtilldate.
Controller action -

```
public function actionIndex3() {
    //$enddate = '2018-03-01';
    $searchModel1 = new SellitemSearch();
    $dataProvider1 = $searchModel1->search ( Yii::$app->request->queryParams );
    //$searchModel2 = new PuritemtilldateSearch();
    //$dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render ( '_formtilldate' , [
                'model1' => $searchModel1 ,
                    //'enddate' => $enddate,
                    //'model2' => $searchModel2,
                    //'searchModel1' => $searchModel2,
    ] );
}
```

And the form field

```
<?php

$form = ActiveForm::begin ( [
            'id' => 'form-id' ,
            'action' => [ '/stock/sellitem/stocktilldate' , 'enddate' => $model1->enddate ] ,
            'method' => 'get' ,
            'enableClientScript' => false ,
        ] );
?>
<?=

$form->field ( $model1 , 'enddate' )->widget (
        DatePicker::className () , [
    // inline too, not bad
    'options' => [ 'placeholder' => 'End Date ...' , 'id' => 'enddate1' ] ,
    'inline' => false ,
    //'id' => 'startdate1',
    // modify template for custom rendering
    //'template' => '<div class="well well-sm" style="background-color: #fff; width:250px">{input}</div>',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true ,
        'todayHighlight' => true ,
        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    ]
] );
?>
```

On clicking on the submit button, the search query runs - 
Controller Action -

```
public function actionStocktilldate( $enddate ) {
    //$enddate = '2018-03-01';
    $searchModel1 = new SellitemtilldateSearch();
    $dataProvider1 = $searchModel1->search ( Yii::$app->request->queryParams );
    //$searchModel2 = new PuritemtilldateSearch();
    //$dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render ( 'indexstocktilldate' , [
                //'enddate' => $enddate,
                'searchModel1' => $searchModel1 ,
                'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1 ,
                    //'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,          
                    //'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
    ] );
}
```

Search Model -

```
public function search( $params , $enddate ) {
    //$query = Sellitem::find();
    $subQuery1 = (new Query() )->select ( [ 'pi_upc' , 'sum(pi_qty) as purchased' ] )->from ( 'puritem' )->leftJoin ( 'pursum' , 'pursum.ps_id = puritem.psi_id' )->andwhere ( [ '<' , 'pursum.ps_date' , $enddate ] )->groupby ( 'pi_upc' );
    $subQuery2 = (new Query() )->select ( [ 'si_iupc' , 'sum(si_qty) as sold' ] )->from ( 'sellitem' )->leftJoin ( 'sellsum' , 'sellsum.ss_id = sellitem.si_ssid' )->andwhere ( [ '<' , 'sellsum.ss_date' , $enddate ] )->groupby ( 'si_iupc' );
    $subQuery3 = (new Query() )->select ( [ 'i_upc' , 'i_category' , 'i_brand' , 'i_desc' , 'i_unit' , 'i_buyprice' , 'coalesce(p.purchased,0) as purchased' ] )->from ( 'item' )->leftJoin ( [ 'p' => $subQuery1 ] , 'p.pi_upc = i_upc' );
    $query = (new Query() )->select ( [ 'tp.i_upc as upc' , 'tp.i_category as category' , 'tp.i_brand as brand' , 'tp.i_desc as description' , 'tp.i_unit as unit' , 'tp.purchased as purchased' , 'coalesce(ts.sold,0) as sold' , '(coalesce(purchased,0) - coalesce(sold,0)) as stock' , 'tp.i_buyprice as rate' , 'round(((coalesce(purchased,0) - coalesce(sold,0))*tp.i_buyprice),2) as value' ] )->from ( [ 'tp' => $subQuery3 ] )->leftJoin ( [ 'ts' => $subQuery2 ] , 'ts.si_iupc = tp.i_upc' );
    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query ,
    'pagination' => [
    'pageSize' => 10000000000 ,
    ] ,
    ]);
    ......
}
```

Now, in the url I can see the parameter got passed -

```
http://localhost/chayanika/frontend/web/index.php?r=stock%2Fsellitem%2Fstocktilldate&SellitemSearch%5Benddate%5D=2018-08-13
```

But, I'm getting error -

```
Bad Request (#400)
Missing required parameter: enddate
```

I'm not getting where I'm missing it.

I made a bit progress here -

I just learned that the date I'm getting in the URL is coming from the Action in the form. But it's not of much use so far.

If I change the controller action a bit, I get a result -

```
public function actionStocktilldate() {
    $enddate = date ( 'Y-m-d' );
    //$enddate = yii::$app->request->get('enddate');
    //var_dump($enddate); 
    $searchModel1 = new SellitemtilldateSearch();
    $dataProvider1 = $searchModel1->search ( Yii::$app->request->queryParams , $enddate );
    //$searchModel2 = new PuritemtilldateSearch();
    //$dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render ( 'indexstocktilldate' , [
                //'enddate' => $enddate,
                'searchModel1' => $searchModel1 ,
                'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1 ,
                    //'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,          
                    //'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
    ] );
}
```

Please tell me how can I pass the date collected by the form to this controller.

Comment: do mark the answer as correct which worked.

Answer (score 0):

In your url, I don't see enddate param, I just see:

`frontend/web/index.php?r=stock/sellitem/stocktilldate&SellitemSearch[enddate]=2018-08-13"`

It is SellitemSearch[enddate], not enddate
You should modify your url to

`frontend/web/index.php?r=stock/sellitem/stocktilldate&enddate=2018-08-13"`
or remove `$enddate` param from `actionStocktilldate` function.

Answer (score 0):

How is `action` parameter treated in ActiveForm.

> Query parameters in the action are ignored for GET method. We use
>   hidden fields to add them back Hidden inputs are created and they are
>   submitted so your form action goes to the right place.

So if you look into the form source from your browser there is a hidden input created with the name `enddate` which will be submitted automatically.

```
<form id="w0" action="http://localhost/chayanika/frontend/web/index.php?r=/stock/sellitem/stocktilldate" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="enddate" value="2018-03-01"><button type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

#### Reason

But in your case, it isn't submitting because there isn't any hidden field being created. Why? because the assignment of your `$model->enddate` is returning `null`. Make sure there is a valid timestamp or date string saved.

#### Track

Go to line 395 of `\yii\web\UrlManager` `function createUrl($params)`.

If you are using `enablePrettyUrl=>true` then it will enter the first check and in the `foreach` it appends the query string params as `key` where **`value!==null`**.

```
if($this->enablePrettyUrl){
            $cacheKey = $route . '?';
            foreach($params as $key => $value){
                if($value !== null){
                    $cacheKey .= $key . '&';
                }
            }
```

if you are using `enablePrettyUrl=>false` then it will skip to the last section

```
 $url = "$baseUrl?{$this->routeParam}=" . urlencode($route);
        if(!empty($params) && ($query = http_build_query($params)) !== ''){
            $url .= '&' . $query;
        }

        return $url . $anchor;
```

and there it will fail the check `if(!empty($params) && ($query = http_build_query($params)) !== ''){` as **`http_build_query($params)`** returns empty string for an array having a key with null value.

So make sure you have a date save and the current model does not have the `date` saved in database as null